# Restoring displayed fragment on activity rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with one main fragment displayed on it. When I rotate the screen, the activity is beeing recreated. What would be the best way to store the info about currently displayed fragment for screen state restore purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method onSaveInstanceState to store values in a bundle:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString(MY_FIRST_KEY,valueToSave);
}
```

then  you can restore the values in the method onRestoreInstanceState

```
 @Override
 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(inState);

    valueToSave = inState.getString(MY_FIRST_KEY);
 }
```

You can also set an xml attribute on TextViews and EditText called "freezeText" which saves any text that was set.

Comment: thats's surely useful advices. Didn't know about freezeText. However, to store the whole fragment I'd have to putSerializable. And to do that, every variable inside the fragment must implemen Serializable. That's troublesome